# How can I configure Windows Firewall without turning the service on?

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, windows-firewall

I suddenly could not RDP into my server after rebooting it. Turned out the Firewall was blocking me, I remotely shut off the firewall service (parallels virtuozzo panel) and was able to RDP in. When I went to add my office IP to the firewall to allow me to connect, it won't launch the control panel unless I enable the Windows Firewall. If I do that, it kicks me off of RDP naturally. So how on earth can I configure this thing?

Comment: Do not cross post. If the Question is on the wrong site we'll move it.

Comment: @ChrisS It seemed to me that it fits on both sites, though probably more relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution!

You can also edit the settings on Registry directly (regedit), under HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy. (This even works over the network, assuming Remote Registry is running.)

For Remote Desktop, under the key StandardProfile\GloballyOpenPorts\List add a string value named 3389:TCP with the data 3389:TCP:*:Enabled:Remote Desktop.

[Thanks to this fine fellow.](https://superuser.com/questions/332565/how-can-i-configure-windows-firewall-without-turning-the-service-on/332574#332574)